# Filemaker: How to move record from table to another table in the same database?

Tags: filemaker

**Filemaker**: How to move record from table to another table in the same database?

Answer (score 0):

Write a script.

Load all field values into variables or global field, change layout, create a new record and set the fields in the other table from the variables/global. Go to the previous table and delete the record you are moving (last could be done straight after you load data into variables)

Two other options: build a temporary relationship to create and populate a new record, or flag the record to move and use FQL to populate data from a target table. Again, need to script both and delete the source record at the end.

Just be careful. The fact what you copy a full record to another table indicates what they might not have to be two different tables.

Comment: Thank Nicolai Kant for your reply, I want move record to another table by only one variable and one time. Please any suggestion?

Comment: Instead of creating multiple variables you can use one variable and store multiple values. You can store your values as a list, convert them to xml or json, whatever you are happy to extract on the other end. Variables also have repetitions like repeated fields, so you can store different values in repetitions, similar to arrays.

Comment: I second the last paragraph.  Probably it is best to make one table out of these two.

Comment: Another simple method is to **import** the required record/s (after isolating them in a found set of the source table). However, I too would question the need for such practice - it suggests a flaw in the way the data is structured.

Comment: @huonsokly P.S. "*I want move record to another table by only one variable*" This requirement makes no sense. Storing multiple values in a single variable is possible - but it is less robust (for example WRT data types) and more difficult to maintain. If you really need to do this, use a dedicated variable for each field. There is nothing to gain by skimping on the amount of variables used.

Comment: @NicolaiKant "*flag the record to move*" That's not something I would suggest.